# Ektorp dependency crashing Spring boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, ektorp

I`m making a web application. The back-end is in Java, and I use Spring. For the database I use CouchDb and I want to use Ektorp, but here comes the problem. It crashes when I add the Ektorp dependency. It compiles, but when I try to run, I get the errors from below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:429)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:420)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at QEasyApplication.main(QEasyApplication.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:442)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 20 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried changing to different versions of Ektorp or spring boot but nothing worked. Down below is my Maven pom file. What could be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ektorp</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.ektorp.spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that `org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener` is not on your classpath. It resides in [`spring-context`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener.java).

You state, in other words your `pom.xml` states, that someone should provide `spring-boot-dependencies` for you? I think you confused the `provided` and the `import` [Maven scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

- `provided` – "you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime"
- `import` – "It indicates the dependency to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's  section."

So two possibilities:

1. switch the `runtime` scope of `spring-boot-dependencies` to `import`
2. **even better**, let Spring Boot manage as many dependencies as possible for you and put the following parent pom in place, to **leverage the full potential** of Spring Boot:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```